# Extension method for nested generic with constraints

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, extension-methods

I have these classes below:

```
public class BootstrapContent<TComponent> : IHtmlContent
        where TComponent : SingleComponent
{
   private readonly TComponent _component;
   internal TComponent Component => _component;
   //and some other codes
}

public abstract class FormControl<TComponent> : SingleComponent
        where TComponent : SingleComponent, IInputComponent
{
    protected abstract TComponent Input { get; }
}

public class FormInput : FormControl<Input>
{
   //implementation here
}

public class Input : InputComponent
{
}

public abstract class InputComponent : SingleComponent,
        IInputComponent
{
}

public abstract class SingleComponent : HtmlComponent
{
}
```

So I need an extension method like this: (specific for BootstrapContent<FormControl derived types > here FormInput as an example) and it will return the same type BootstrapContent (for fluent design).

```
public static BootstrapContent<TComponent> InputOpts<TComponent, TInput>(this BootstrapContent<TComponent> bootstrapContent)
  where TComponent : FormControl<TInput>
  where TInput : SingleComponent, IInputComponent
{
   ...
}
```

and when I want to call this something like below:

```
var content = new BootstrapContent<FormInput>();

content.InputOpts();
```

I get compiler error

> "CS0411:The type arguments for method 'method' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

I am missing something here but I can not see. I need an extension method for BootstrapContent where T is any derivation of FormControl. I assume it can be done but how?

Anyone who may help?

(I tried to add the signatures of classes here not unnecessary implementations.)

Thanks.

Comment: For the extension method, the compiler needs to know the types for both `TComponent` and `TInput`. Try using `content.InputOpts<FormInput, Input>();` to specify the type arguments explicitly. Consider not using `TInput` on your extension method signature because it's not a type for an argument or a return value for the method.

Comment: Can you please show your interfaces declarations? I'm interested about how the types used on interface level an is it possible to make interfaces generic and use `in/out` keywords

Comment: @JonathanDodds thx for ur reply. It is really helpful. So here the type of "Input" class can not be inferred from the "FormInput" (despite it is FormControl<Input>) class and will I always have to specify these two types? Actually this is something I do not want. I expected the compiler infer the "Input" type from FormInput which is FormControl<Input>.